# Clean cache work on iOS 7 and iOS 8,however,on iOS 9 and iOS 10,it didn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The code I use to clean cache is:

```
-(void)removeCache
{
    NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:cachePath];

for (NSString *p in files)
{
    NSError *error;
    NSString *path = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:p];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }
}
}
```

It work fine on both iOS 7 and iOS 8,but on iOS 9 and iOS 10,it didn't work.I add a breakpoint in this method,it stoped there,so,the method had been called but it didn't clean caches on iOS 9 and iOS 10.

**I am really very curious about why it work fine on iOS 7 and iOS 8,but,didn't work on iOS 9 and iOS 10.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a three part named EGOImageView in my project,and it will cache images,so the right way to clean cache is use EGOImage's own clean method.